# How to drag and drop Image into Photoshop without creating a new layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is there a way to drag and drop and image into photoshop on an active layer rather than it creating a new layer in Photoshop CC 2021?

Comment: No. Why the default behavior is an issue?

Comment: trying to make a repetitive task less time consuming, have set up masks that I don't want to drag onto the new layer

Comment: Ah, makes sense. In this case only workarounds: use a linked smart object with a mask and replace its contents, create a group with a mask and place images inside the group, use Apply to transfer mask between the source and target layers, etc...

Comment: Yes, I figured that would be best

Comment: Drop then merge down....